# Cell change color based on cell range

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I am building a Google Sheets to check off vocabulary words taught during a school year. I need the cells in the first column (the vocabulary word) to change to green when taught, or red when not taught. I am recording the date taught in the adjacent row cells. For example B1 will turn red if there is no data in cells C1:AA1.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can use conditional formatting for `B1` using the "Custom Formula Is" option and use `=CountA(C1:AA1)=0` then turn it red. Copy and paste the formatting down the B column.

Comment: Please don't tag with Excel unless you actually use Excel. There are a lot of differences between Google Sheets and Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Please format as much of B:B as relevant "standard" red then select B:B, clear any CF formatting from it and Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=countblank(C1:AA1)<>25
```

Select green formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.